# Sums of binomial coefficients weighted by rational numbers

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I know from numerical evaluation that for all $n \ge 0$ and for any $\alpha$ which is positive real value

$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{k + \alpha }}} \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}n\\k
\end{array}} \right) = \frac{{\Gamma \left( \alpha  \right)!n!}}{{\Gamma \left( {n + \alpha  + 1} \right)}}$   .

See [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SqY_iBVL0welvWjBMH79N7RKeW5ye8OJ/view?usp=sharing) for a proof (by induction) in the special case of $\alpha$ being an integer, but addressing the general case eludes me.  Does anyone have any ideas of how to proceed?

Also, it is not hard to prove that

$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{1}{{k + 1}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}n\\k
\end{array}} \right)}  = \frac{{{2^{n + 1}} - 1}}{{n + 1}}$   ,

which look remarkably similar for the case $\alpha = 1$. Does anyone know if the non-alternating sum has a similar closed form for a more general case, either integer or real?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, note that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k+\alpha}{\binom nk}=\sum_{k=0}^n
\int_0^1 (-1)^k\binom nkx^{k+\alpha-1}\,dx=\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^n
\,dx.$$
This is a beta integral, and equals
$$B(\alpha,n+1)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}
=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)n!}{\Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}.$$

Comment: Thanks!  Noticed the answer looked like a beta function, but didn't think to turn the sum into an integral.  Will see if this can help address the second also.

Comment: @JohnPolcari You'll get $(1+x)^n$ instead, leading to  a less tractable integral.

Comment: agreed, but I wonder what happens if you then change x to -x (or maybe 1+x to y).  Will depend on what is available for beta function identities.